# Rails 3 upgrade: Generate routing tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, routes

At the moment I'm working on an upgrade from Rails 2.3.smthn to Rails 3.0.
The application has 200+ routes, and, before rewriting the routes using the new Router API, I want to write (RSpec) tests for the routes.

Because there are a lot of routes and writing the coverage for them would be a lot of 'grunt work', I was wondering if there is a way to generate the tests for those routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colleague of mine and I wrote a gem that generates route specs for every route in a Rails app, you can see the source and get it [here](https://github.com/wkirschbaum/route_tractor).

Answer (score 0):

I would use `rake routes` to list your current routes then write a little Ruby program to parse each line and generate the tests you want, of the form:

```
expect(:get => "/articles/2012/11/when-to-use-routing-specs").to route_to(
  :controller => "articles",
  :month => "2012-11",
  :slug => "when-to-use-routing-specs"
)
```

as described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs

I'm not sure how to test the named routes, however, or how to test that there are *no other routes defined*. You might want to complement this with a test which compares the previous output of `rake routes` to the current output of `rake routes`.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of writing a tiny Ruby program that would parse the `rake routes` output and generate a spec for each route. I was curious if anyone has figured out a way of doing this via a script and/or a gem of some kind. If I don't get a promising answer throughout the weekend I think that I will start writing the parser.